# Check if current time is 1 minute past previously-saved time in PHP

Tags: php

I'm saving the time to a variable called $time, using `$time = time()`, and later on, I need to be able to check to see if the current time is greater than 1 minute by comparing the current time with the previously-saved time.

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: Is `later on` still in the same script? Otherwise you could use a `session` to store the time and retrieve it later

Comment: save $time in database, & then compair saved time $time with current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the time to database or session, but this is how you would check

```
$time = time();

if((time() - $time) > 60){
    echo 'past 1 minute';
}
```